# How to update database from POCO using EF 4.4 with existing DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

Technologies used:

- SQL Server 2012
- ASP.NET MVC 4
- EF 4.4
- Windows 8 Pro (dev machine)
- Windows Server 2012

I was using EF with database updates being handled by EF but without migrations, few people + short time. We went into production and some after-prod changes were necessary, EF without migrations was complicating things now that we couldn't just drop the table anymore. Since we were short on time I decided to disable the integration (`Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);`) and make all changes (DB and POCO) by hand.

Now I need to reactivate that functionality. My question is, **can I activate migrations now with this environment already set and with plenty of data**?

I've read this article with no success:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/data/tools.aspx) to update your production environment instead. It provides more control than just what entity framework created (e.g. stored procedures).

If you don't know what you have changed, create a new (empty) database from your **updated** `DbContext`. Then use SSDT to compare the newly created database with the production database. It will show what you have changed in the database schema and provide an update script. Data comparison and 
 'smart insert' based on existing data is also supported.

Comment: Ok, this solves my problem about updating my current database. But I also want to let EF handle this from now on. So, would you know how to, and if is possible to enable migrations at this point? Thanks.